# Enabled SSL - Login Doesn't work

Tags: users, ssl

Followed the instructions on enabling SSL on Drupal 7 installation.

The SSL loads fine, all pages/links work but I'm unable to login.

When I try to login the screen just resets, go back to http and all works fine.

Any ideas what I may have missed?

Tried following the instructions twice now.

Regards,

Richard

Comment: Having the exact same issue. Working on it, please provide info if you solved it.

Comment: Are you using the Secure Pages module? I've had much luck with that automatically handling SSL for me.

Answer (score 0):

It was a cookie issue. When I deleted all the cookies from browser it was fine.